# delete and erasing an iter?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i'm initializing and inserting into a list like so

```
_ARRAY_DETAIL* pAR = new _ARRAY_DETAIL;
pAR->sVar1 = 1;
pAR->nVar2 = 2;
m_SomeList.push_back(pAR);
```

i am trying to find and erase all from the list that contains the value 1, and then delete the pointer we created with `new`, is my example below doing both in a good, correct efficient way?

```
while(Iter != m_SomeList.end());
{
    if((*Iter)->sVar1 == 1) 
    {
        _ARRAY_DETAIL* pAR = *Iter;
        Iter = m_SomeList.erase(Iter);
        delete  pAR;    pAR = NULL;
    }

    Iter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an alternative you could use `remove if` although what you have done seems fine.

```
 bool IsOne (_ARRAY_DETAIL* pAR) { 
   if(pAR->sVar1 == 1) {
    delete pAR;
    return true;
   }
   return false;
 }

 remove_if (vec.begin(), vec.end(), IsOne);
```

Comment: `list::remove_if` is better than a custom loop.  Storage of raw pointers complicates this usage though.

Answer (score 2):

Once you erase the iterator, it's no longer valid. You need to increment it before the erase.

```
if((*Iter)->sVar1 == 1) 
{
    _ARRAY_DETAIL* pAR = *Iter;
    m_SomeList.erase(Iter++);
    delete pAR;
}
else
    ++Iter;
```

You were correct that `erase` [returns an incremented iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) but I prefer to do it explicitly, before the iterator is erased.

Setting pAR to NULL is redundant, since it's going out of scope on the next line anyway.

Also note that you should only increment `Iter` if you didn't increment it in the other part of the `if`.

Comment: `erase()` returning a new iterator is in the Standard (§23.2.3/12)

Comment: "*You were correct that `erase` returns an incremented iterator but I prefer to do it explicitly, before the iterator is erased.*" This seems really silly -- the same would not work for `std::vector<>`, so why not opt for consistency and use the approach that would work for _all_ containers?

Comment: @ildjarn, it was `std::vector::erase` that I was looking at. It's that confusion over which methods do and which don't return an iterator that makes me prefer to increment by myself.